# Regex: how to select characters that follow <something> without selecting that <something>?

Tags: regex

I want to select !! that follow any non-white-space word, without selecting any part of the word.

For example, take this simple expression: `[^ ]!!`

In will select the ***bold&italic*** of the following:

> !Thi***s!!***And!ThisOn***e!!***
>
> But not !! any of these !! !

That is selecting what I want, but in addition it's also selecting the last character of the words. Basically what I want the selection to look like is this:

> !This***!!***And!ThisOne***!!***
>
> But not !! any of these !! !

Is there a way to do that in Regex? Of course, in code I could just find all the matches, and then replace all the matches with `the matches - the first character`. But I was hoping there is a way to do with just regex.

Comment: You're looking for a _lookahead_ or _lookbehind_

Comment: @ti7 Looks like you're right, but I'm still having a lot of difficulty getting what I want. Trying to follow some tutorials right now.

Comment: Please tag the language you are using. Regexs will vary depending on the engine they use.

Comment: Well I was just using https://regexr.com/ for now, but my language is C#. In any case looks like some posted the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a look behind that asserts the previous char is a "word" character:

```
(?<=\w)!!
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/KT9ObMiCTTEv15).

Look arounds assert without consuming, so any input they match is not part of the overall match.

Comment: Thank you! I was getting frustrated because I was trying to use `(?<[^ ])!!`, which seems like it would be effectively the same thing but it wasn't working. What the reason why that doesn't work? To me that seem like they should be the same thing; bath have one "negative".

Comment: You had a syntax problem `(?<[^ ])!!` should be `(?<=[^ ])!!` (you were missing the equals sign). btw, If this answer best answers your question, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it by clicking the tick to the left of this answer.